# how can i know user allowed kernel extension from security&privacy in high sierra

Tags: objective-c, macos-high-sierra, kernel-extension

I created kernel extension for mac high sierra.

When i load kernel extension file in high sierra user should allow from security & privacy.

How can i verify that user allowed my kernel extension from security & privacy?
Is there any file in which user allowed kernel extension detail are stored.

Answer (score 2):

The information about approvals is stored in `sqlite3` database:

```
/var/db/SystemPolicyConfiguration/KextPolicy
```

The table is `kext_policy`. E.g.

```
sqlite3 /var/db/SystemPolicyConfiguration/KextPolicy
select * from kext_policy;
```

BTW, I have no idea how much you can rely on this, i.e. whether Apple will decide to change this in Mojave or any future MacOS release.

There is also `spctl kext-consent <action>` command, but it does not work properly on my 10.13.6 system. Maybe this will be the "correct" approach in the future.